# Finding MAX and MIN values for each same start and end week

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a query I am trying to implement in which I am not having much success with in trying to find the MAX and MIN for each week.

I have 2 Tables:

SYMBOL_DATA (contains open,high,low,close, and volume)
WEEKLY_LOOKUP (contains a list of weeks(no weekends) with a WEEK_START and WEEK_END)

```
**SYMBOL_DATA Example:**
OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME
23.22 26.99 21.45 22.49 34324995
```

WEEKLY_LOOKUP (contains a list of weeks(no weekends) with a WEEK_START and WEEK_END)

```
**WEEKLY_LOOKUP Example:**

WEEK_START  WEEK_END
2016-01-25  2016-01-29  
2016-01-18  2016-01-22
2016-01-11  2016-01-15
2016-01-04  2016-01-08
```

I am trying to find for each WEEK_START and WEEK_END the high and low for that particular week.

For instance, if the WEEK is WEEK_START=2016-01-11 and WEEK_END=2016-01-15, I would have
5 entries for that particular symbol listed:

```
DATE        HIGH     LOW
2016-01-15  96.38    93.54
2016-01-14  98.87    92.45
2016-01-13  100.50   95.21
2016-01-12  99.96    97.55
2016-01-11  98.60    95.39

2016-01-08  100.50   97.03
2016-01-07  101.43   97.30
2016-01-06  103.77   100.90
2016-01-05  103.71   101.67
2016-01-04  102.24   99.76
```

For each week_ending (2016-01-15) the HIGH is 100.50 on 2016-01-13 and the LOW is 92.45 on 2016-01-14

I attempted to write a query that gives me a list of highs and lows, but when I tried adding a MAX(HIGH), I had only 1 row returned back.
I tried a few more things in which I couldn't get the query to work (some sort of infinite run type). For now, I just have this that gives me a list of highs and lows for every day instead of the roll-up for each week which I am not sure how to do.

```
select date, t1.high, t1.low 
from SYMBOL_DATA t1, WEEKLY_LOOKUP t2 
where symbol='ABCDE' and (t1.date>=t2.START_DATE and t1.date<=t2.END_DATE) 
                     and t1.date<=CURDATE() 
LIMIT 30;
```

How can I get for each week (Start and End) the High_Date, MAX(High), and Low_Date, MIN(LOW) found each week?  I probably don't need a 
full history for a symbol, so a LIMIT of like 30 or (30 week periods) would be sufficient so I can see trending.

If I wanted to know for example each week MAX(High) and MIN(LOW) start week ending 2016-01-15 the result would show

```
**Result:**
WEEK_ENDING 2016-01-15 100.50 2016-01-13 92.45 2016-01-14
WEEK_ENDING 2016-01-08 103.77 2016-01-06 97.03 2016-01-08
etc
etc
```

Thanks to all of you with the expertise and knowledge. I greatly appreciate your help very much.

**Edit**
Once the Week Ending list is returned containing the MAX(HIGH) and MIN(LOW) for each week, is it possible then on how to find the MAX(HIGH) and MIN(LOW) from that result set so it return then only 1 entry from the 30 week periods?
Thank you!

**To Piotr**

```
select part1.end_date,part1.min_l,part1.max_h,  s1.date, part1.min_l,s2.date from 
(
select t2.start_date, t2.end_date, max(t1.high) max_h, min(t1.low) min_l
from SYMBOL_DATA t1, WEEKLY_LOOKUP t2 
where symbol='FB' 
and t1.date<='2016-01-22' 
and (t1.date>=t2.START_DATE and t1.date<=t2.END_DATE)
group by t2.start_date, t2.end_date order by t1.date DESC LIMIT 1;
) part1, symbol_data s1, symbol_data s2
where part1.max_h = s1.high and part1.min_l = s2.low;
```

[image]
You will notice that the MAX and MIN for each week is staying roughly the same and not changing as it should be different for week to week for both the High and Low.

Comment: Why do you have a table of weeks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f156d/4)

I have abbreviated some of your names in my example.

Getting the high and low for each week is pretty simple; you just have to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT s1.symbol, w.week_end, MAX(s1.high) AS weekly_high, MIN(s1.LOW) as weekly_low
FROM weeks AS w
INNER JOIN symdata AS s1 ON s1.zdate BETWEEN w.week_start AND w.week_end
GROUP BY s1.symbol, w.week_end
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f156d/4/0)**:

```
| symbol |                  week_end | weekly_high | weekly_low |
|--------|---------------------------|-------------|------------|
|   ABCD | January, 08 2016 00:00:00 |      103.77 |      97.03 |
|   ABCD | January, 15 2016 00:00:00 |       100.5 |      92.45 |
```

Unfortunately, getting the dates of the high and low requires that you re-join to the symbol_data table, based on the symbol, week and values.  And even *that* doesn't do the job; you have to account for the possibility that there might be two days where the same high (or low) was achieved, and decide which one to choose.  I arbitrarily chose the first occurrence in the week of the high and low.  So to get that second level of choice, you need another GROUP BY.  The whole thing winds up looking like this:

```
SELECT wl.symbol, wl.week_end, wl.weekly_high, MIN(hd.zdate) as high_date, wl.weekly_low, MIN(ld.zdate) as low_date
FROM (
  SELECT s1.symbol, w.week_start, w.week_end, MAX(s1.high) AS weekly_high, MIN(s1.low) as weekly_low
  FROM weeks AS w
  INNER JOIN symdata AS s1 ON s1.zdate BETWEEN w.week_start AND w.week_end
  GROUP BY s1.symbol, w.week_end) AS wl
INNER JOIN symdata AS hd 
  ON hd.zdate BETWEEN wl.week_start AND wl.week_end
  AND hd.symbol = wl.symbol
  AND hd.high = wl.weekly_high
INNER JOIN symdata AS ld
  ON ld.zdate BETWEEN wl.week_start AND wl.week_end
  AND ld.symbol = wl.symbol
  AND ld.low = wl.weekly_low
GROUP BY wl.symbol, wl.week_start, wl.week_end, wl.weekly_high, wl.weekly_low
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f156d/4/1)**:

```
| symbol |                  week_end | weekly_high |                 high_date | weekly_low |                  low_date |
|--------|---------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|------------|---------------------------|
|   ABCD | January, 08 2016 00:00:00 |      103.77 | January, 06 2016 00:00:00 |      97.03 | January, 08 2016 00:00:00 |
|   ABCD | January, 15 2016 00:00:00 |       100.5 | January, 13 2016 00:00:00 |      92.45 | January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for submitting your answer for this. Appreciate your help as well.  I will be able to give you an update in 10 mins of the results.

Comment: I confirmed the result and it is spot on. I checked each week high and low against another source for the weekly data, and then checked the dates on the daily of when the high or low was detected - it was all correct. The execution is very quick as well.  I ended up adding after the first INNER JOIN an AND symbol='ABCDE' and wl.week_end<='xxxx-xx-xx' so that it will start at a particular time period. I then added in a LIMIT 30.  You did an amazing job on the query.  You made it look so simple, but yet I recognize there is no way I could have constructed this.  Thank you Sir!

Comment: Hi Alan. Constructing these type of queries is challenging to me.  Is there a book you highly recommend that will give a solid foundation and can take me through a process of being able to construct embedded queries as you have done?

Comment: Hey Alan, with having the results being returned as you have shown, how can another query be wrapped around to where it returns say just 2 results (I guess it can't be in 1 correct?) of 1 row being the MAX(HIGH) entry and another row being the MIN(LOW) so that it picks the HIGHEST HIGH and LOWEST LOW from the return results?

Comment: I tried adding something like SELECT SYMBOL,end_date, high_date, MAX(weekly_high), low_date, MIN(weekly_low) as lowest_low from (... your query ... ).  So it finds the MAX and LOW from the result set, but the dates were wrong as they ended up with dates from the most recent week.  I found out of my 30 week limit that the MAX(High) occurred on 2015-11-05 and MIN(Low) occurred on 2015-08-24.  How can I get the Highest High value and it's date and the Lowest Low value with its date of when it occurred from the the query you made?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I only used low_date and MIN(weekly_low) and then added GROUP by low_date ORDER BY weekly_low ASC LIMIT 1;  When I did that, it returned 2015-08-24 with the 72.00 value.  I will try now for the high value. I did the same except MAX(High) and changed the ASC to DESC which gave me 2015-11-05 with the 110.65 value.  I suppose there is no way to do both of these in 1 query? or have to run the query twice to get the results for each?

Comment: Sorry, haven't read a SQL book in years.  I have been writing SQL queries much more complex than this, for over 20 years.  That's how I learned it.

Comment: If you frequently want to make use of a particular query, like the answer I posted, you can define it as a VIEW, and then query it as if it were just another table.

Comment: If I answered your question, it helps if you mark this as "the answer"

Comment: I tried to do the CREATE VIEW myview AS (your query) but it wouldn't create because I have sub queries.  I think I had somewhere that you can push those results into a temp_table and then query?  Then I could do 2 queries with a INNER JOIN to get the Highest High and Lowest Low with the ending week associated.

Comment: Since the VIEW wouldn't work, I dropped the results into a TEMP_TABLE1 and TEMP_TABLE 2, then did an inner join on 2 queries, 1 for the Highest High and 1 for the Lowest Low from each week within my limit.

Comment: Ah yes, MySQL doesn't support putting subqueries in views.  Actually, there is a (truly nasty) way to do it.  You can put the subquery into a view of its own, and then join to that subquery in the outer view.  In your particular case that could be a helpful approach, because you could use the inner view for both your weekly summary (the original question) and your global summary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101687/discussion-between-alan-hadsell-and-livefire).

Answer (score 1):

To get the global highs and lows, just remove the `weekly` table from the original query:

```
SELECT wl.symbol, wl.high, MIN(hd.zdate) as high_date, wl.low, MIN(ld.zdate) as low_date
FROM (
  SELECT s1.symbol, MAX(s1.high) AS high, MIN(s1.low) as low
  FROM symdata AS s1 
  GROUP BY s1.symbol) AS wl
INNER JOIN symdata AS hd 
  ON hd.symbol = wl.symbol
  AND hd.high = wl.high
INNER JOIN symdata AS ld
  ON ld.symbol = wl.symbol
  AND ld.low = wl.low
GROUP BY wl.symbol, wl.high, wl.low
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/178b71/3/0)**:

```
| symbol |   high |                 high_date |   low |                  low_date |
|--------|--------|---------------------------|-------|---------------------------|
|   ABCD | 103.77 | January, 06 2016 00:00:00 | 92.45 | January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Thank you Alan. Is there a way to get the global highs and lows with the weekly table in place with your original answer above?  That way I can pinpoint to exactly what closing week it was associated with.  I am very thankful for all of your help. There is no way I could have figured this out given my level... extremely appreciative for your knowledge and time.

Answer (score 1):

The week table seems entirely redundant...

```
SELECT symbol
     , WEEK(zdate)
     , MIN(low) min
     , MAX(high) max_high 
  FROM symdata 
 GROUP 
    BY symbol, WEEK(zdate);
```

This is a simplified example. In reality, you might use DATE_FORMAT or something like that instead.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c247f/3

Answer (score 0):

Check if following query produces desired result:

```
    select part1.end_date,part1.min_l,part1.max_h,  s1.date, part1.min_l,s2.date from 
    (
    select t2.start_date, t2.end_date, max(t1.high) max_h, min(t1.low) min_l
    from SYMBOL_DATA t1, WEEKLY_LOOKUP t2 
    where symbol='ABCDE' 
    and (t1.date>=t2.START_DATE and t1.date<=t2.END_DATE)
    group by t2.start_date, t2.end_date
    ) part1, symbol_data s1, symbol_data s2
    where part1.max_h = s1.high and part1.min_l = s2.low
and (s1.date >= part1.start_date and part1.end_date)
and (s2.date >= part1.start_date and part1.end_date)
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr for your assistance and help.  I will check the results and let you know the outcome very shortly.

Comment: Hi Piotr, I tried the query. The query goes into a continuous run that doesn't return results.  After 5 mins of running, I didn't have results back.

Comment: The WEEKLY_LOOKUP table does have several years of week_ending dates from 2013 up to future 2018.  I tried adding after symbol='ABCDE' to put a t1.date<='2016-01-22' so that maybe it would start there, I added a ORDER by t1.date (?) as I want most recent entries first and a LIMIT of 10 to see what happens. When I did that, it did return back, but the results didn't appear to look correct.  I will post results above.

Comment: Edited query to add filters to date column. Check if it will give better results

Comment: Hi Piotr, I tried the query with the filters but for some reason, the query kept running for several minutes without results being returned. I eventually had to interrupt it.

Comment: Run again my updated query with following at the end: and (s1.date >= part1.start_date and part1.end_date)
and (s2.date >= part1.start_date and part1.end_date)

Comment: Hi Piotr, I tried running your updated query. It kept running and didn't return results.